# Ambiguous byte definition in rpcndr and cstddef

Tags: c++, visual-studio

We recently moved to visual studio 2019, I wanted to take advantage of [std::filesystem::create_directory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory), which is available in c++17. I changed the project properties to enable c++17

```
Properties
    C/C++
        Language
            C++ Language Standard: ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)
```

Now begins the error nightmare, apparently, byte now has two definitions

**1) rpcndr.h**

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

**2) cstddef**

```
enum class byte : unsigned char {};
```

I changed all the uses of `byte` to `unsigned char`, our code is "byte free". However, I am still getting errors as its being used by other windows headers.

How can I fix this without modifying windows sdk as suggested in [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/93889/error-c2872-byte-ambiguous-symbol.html?fbclid=IwAR38DUbm2YFQjSoZ_vHU__GkuZnJAvqSv-9WWKQPaBlIxEsEiqSHBpRb1aY)?

Comment: What is making `std::byte` an option? That's what the namespace is designed to prevent. I can't imagine that SDK header has a using-directive in it.

Comment: std::byte has cause quite a bit of havoc, collides pretty heavily with RPC sensibilities from the 1980s.  Add `_HAS_STD_BYTE=0` to the preprocessor definitions.  Or just put the code in its own .cpp file so you don't have to #include any windows headers.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, this is actually the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059048/ambiguous-byte-definition-in-rpcndr-and-cstddef/58060367#comment102515332_58059048):

`std::byte` has cause quite a bit of havoc, collides pretty heavily with RPC sensibilities from the 1980s. Add `_HAS_STD_BYTE=0` to the preprocessor definitions. Or just put the code in its own .cpp file so you don't have to #include any windows headers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my QT project when using MSVC2017 with c++17.
In my case, adding:

```
DEFINES +="_HAS_STD_BYTE=0"
```

to the .pro file fixed the issue.